# PySpark error when converting a DataFrame to rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running code in the `pyspark` shell on an `emr` cluster, and encountering an error I have never seen before...

This line works:

```
spark.read.parquet(s3_input).take(99)
```

While this line causes an exception:

```
spark.read.parquet(s3_input).rdd.take(99)
```

With

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Are you sure the transformation code is as you have it in the post? If that's the case, then that error cannot be explained... Are you running some `map` operation on the rdd?

Comment: These are the exact 2 lines I run on my cluster, with the same `s3_input`

Answer (score 0):

The problem persists in pyspark 2.3.0, I have downgraded to pyspark 2.2.1.

This is not a solution, but a workaround until this issue will be fixed by the pyspark maintainers.

Comment: Rather a problem with your configuration. Likely you've submitted to Spark 2.3 but used Spark 2.2 Python library which was on the path.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the `toPandas` question ?

Comment: Because underlying problem is the same - Pandas are not really relevant, and the issue comes from incorrect Spark deployment configuration.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you came up with a solution. Even if the solution is the same, the question and the exceptions are not related.

If you believe that the answer for the `pandas` question also applies here, please post it here.

To make my argument even more absurd, think about all the technical issues that can be solved by restarting your windows machine. Are they all the same issue ?